# How to open server Port for public so that i can access my locally hosted NODEJS server

Tags: sql, node.js, api

**MAKING THINGS SIMPLE EDITS**

I am developing an app, have a nodejs API that read data through MSSQL server, now that API is Running on Localhost:3131/ It means it will run locally only.
I do have a Windows Server that stays online always, I can use pm2 on that server with the API files to make things Live, But if i run it how can i make my SERVER IP Public so I can access it through everywhere.

HOW DO I MAKE MY SERVER IP ONLINE BUT SECURE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you desire. If you were to do it on your own network/pc then one traditional method called 'port forwarding' can be used for projects under development, but this still means that your IP will be exposed to the web.

Virtual Private Servers and Dedicated servers are used more commonly used these days to host powerful applications. You would need to run a web server first where your web files can be hosted and then you can link your node.js server and sql database.

There are several hosting providers out there which are built for nodejs applications. You can go for 'unmanaged' and 'managed' hosting providers.

Managed providers provide a simplified "Node Appliance" solution. Node and NPM will already be set up for you, and deploys are typically done via git push or similar method. You will have less control of your server, but everything will be set up for you.

There are some managed hosting providers which nodejs recommend themselves. You can view them here:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Node-Hosting

Some popular ones include:

- Heroku
- Amazon Web Services
- AppFog
- Microsoft Azure
- RedHat OpenShift

In your case, you are using SQL and Node, so Heroku actually offers free nodejs hosting and provides a free addon for MySQL databases too. Only downside is that the duration (hours) for which you can run apps are limited.

It might be worth doing this on a Virtual Private Server for lower costs. Alternatively, have a look at [NodeChef](https://www.nodechef.com/nodejs-mysql-hosting) who specialise in Node.js and MySQL.

Hopefully, this gives you enough information to understand what steps to take next.